# Coolant flows straighr from rad to muffler?

Tags: nissan, coolant, leak, exhaust-manifold, muffler

Had my 2008 pathfinder towed last week it broke down and I thought it was a starting issue due to corroded post clamps,  replaced those and it runs, but... now filling the rad the fluid runs straight to the muffler where it pours out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Usually that indicates there is an issue with either a head gasket problem or a cracked block. In either case, it's not good and is going to be major surgery or engine replacement. From your description, there's no way of knowing *how* this might have come about. Whatever did cause it or how ever it occured, doesn't really matter at this point. You're going to need to get it fixed before you can do much more with the vehicle.

Comment: could be a hole in the head too, but yeah, the engine is coming apart to diagnose this.